# wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) in semantic_form_for tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

project details
ruby 2.4.1p111 and rails 4.2.8

Below is the code from my index page.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @threshold_configuration, :url => dm_threshold_configuration_path do |f| %>
//my code goes here//
<% end %>
```

in my index action i have the instance variable set.

```
def index
  super
  @threshold_configuration = ThresholdValues.first
end
```

when i load the page getting below error.

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

If i replace the semantic_form_for as below my page is loading.

```
<%= semantic_form_for :threshold_configuration, :url => dm_threshold_configuration_path do |f| %>
//my code goes here//
<% end %>
```

i'm not getting what exactly happening in the @threshold_configuration and :threshold_configuration. syntax which im using is fine according the formstatic gem manual.

Thnx in advance

Ajith

Comment: What would happen if you changed it to: `semantic_form_for(@threshold_configuration, :url => dm_threshold_configuration_path)`

Comment: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) error

Comment: Damn, really? I only asked becuase sometimes ruby doesn't like it when you don't put parentheses around args and you have a block (lambda style), thought that might be the trouble. At the moment, the only thing I can suggest is to make the hash explicit by wrapping it in braces like this: `semantic_form_for(@threshold_configuration, {url: dm_threshold_configuration_path})`. Also, have you tried it without setting the url ( get that setting the url is important, but just to see if it errors).

Comment: After looking (I'm guessing you're using formtastic)I found that the method has the following signature:  `def semantic_form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)`, the first arg is explicit, the rest is a spalt so you shouldn't be getting an error like `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) error`, are you sure this is exactly where the error is happening? can you show the exception stack?

Comment: somebody overridden forms_helper.rb file in the project and it is causing the problem.